# OAuth 2 Requesting a new Access Token uses up Refresh Token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Quick question, couldn't find the answer here. When using the refresh token to create a new access token, will this use up the refresh token?

I had an instance where I used up the refresh token to get a new Access Token however the new access token didn't come with a new refresh token.

Does this mean that I can keep using the initial refresh token every time the access token runs out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) says,

> **`refresh_token`**:  A token that may be used to obtain a new access token. Refresh tokens are valid until the user revokes access.

**Refresh tokens are valid until they are revoked**, so you can use it as many times as you want if it is valid.

The following is an example of refreshing an access_token with Google OAuth.

**Request**

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
refresh_token=1/6BMfW9j53gdGImsiyUH5kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

**Response**

```
{
  "access_token":"1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
}
```

to conclude, refresh tokens are not expired with an access token refresh. they can be used as long as they are valid.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on OAuth 2.0 implementations. Google's implementation is just one example. As a matter of fact, there exists an implementation that allows an administrator to select either (1) to keep a refresh token valid after use or (2) to invalidate a refresh token after use and issue a new one.

[image]